# Upgrade a connection to TLS in Go

Tags: go, ssl

I have an open TCP connection and read from it with a for loop like so

```
for {
  // tx.Text is of type textproto.Conn
  // the underlying connection is stored in tx.Conn
  l, err := tx.Text.Reader.ReadLine()

  // do stuff with the text line ...
}
```

Now I want to upgrade the connection to TLS like this (`TlsConf` contains a certificate loaded with `tls.LoadX509KeyPair`)

```
tx.Conn = tls.Server(tx.Conn, tx.Server.Conf.TlsConf)
tx.Text = textproto.NewConn(tx.Conn)
```

When I do this I get a segmentation fault on the client when the server attempts a handshake. I'm implementing a SMTP server and am testing it with [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) using the `-tls` flag. The terminal output of [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) is the following

```
-> STARTTLS
<-  220 Start TLS
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Since swaks is a tested tool, and worked with the nodeJS SMTP implementation I had before, I don't suspect the error is on the client side.

What did I do wrong or what is missing?

PS: When a TLS connection is started from an existing insecure connection, what does exactly happen? Does the client establish a new connection on a different port or is the connection reused?

Comment: I can not answer why your client is segfaulting, but I can tell you what is happening. When you wrap an existing Conn in a tls.Conn, the client does not need to reconnect. What it does is require standard TLS negotiations as if this was a new TLS connection the next time you Read(). I have no idea what you are missing and why your client is segfaulting. I would say it is a poorly written client if a server can make it segfault in any way.

Comment: I agree with Stephen: the client sounds suspect. What does the client look like?

Comment: A segfault in the client is a remote root exploit waiting to happen - you might want to report it!

Comment: Now that I know the client, quick search turned up http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=675009 . Apparently there was a problem with a certain version of OpenSSL that caused segfaults when using TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditched swaks, built a small tool to test TLS using Go's own smtp.SendMail:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
  err := smtp.SendMail(
    "127.0.0.1:2525",
    nil,
    "src@test.local",
    []string{"dst@test.local"},
    []byte("Hello! Just testing."),
  )
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work as expected with upgrading a TCP session to TLS?

Comment: Yes. Seems to be a problem with swak's TLS negotiation (seems it can't handle TLSv1)

Answer (score 14):

**Here's how to upgrade a net.conn to tls.con:**

1) Somewhere in your code, you have these variables defined

```
var TLSconfig *tls.Config
...
// conn is a normal connection of type net.Conn
conn, err := listener.Accept()
...
```

2) Initialize TLSConfig somewhere above, do something like this

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("/path/to/cert", "/path/to/key")
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
TLSconfig = &tls.Config{
Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, 
ClientAuth: tls.VerifyClientCertIfGiven, 
ServerName: "example.com"}
```

3) At this point you are reading/writing to a standard connection.

When the client issues STARTTLS command, do this in your server:

```
// Init a new TLS connection. I need a *tls.Conn type 
// so that I can do the Handshake()
var tlsConn *tls.Conn
tlsConn = tls.Server(client.socket, TLSconfig)
// run a handshake
tlsConn.Handshake()
// Here is the trick. Since I do not need to access 
// any of the TLS functions anymore,
// I can convert tlsConn back in to a net.Conn type
conn = net.Conn(tlsConn)
```

Next, you may probably update your buffers with the new connection, etc.

Test your server like this:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect  example.com:25
```

This allows you to interact with the server through the tls connection and you can issue some commands, etc.

### More about conversions in Go

I guess conversions are another reason for what makes Go so powerful!

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions

Comment: `tlsConn.Handshake()` is not necessary. It will be executed automatically by the first read according to docs.

Comment: Also openssl seems to have a problem with TLSv1, unless you append `-tls1` to the command.

Comment: true, you don't need to call Handshake(). Strange, though, seems to work for me without appending -tls1

Comment: Maybe we have different openssl versions

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012. I also find this site useful:http://www.checktls.com/perl/TestReceiver.pl - does a nice report for you.

Comment: I have OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

Comment: sweet i was wondering how to check tls credentials on an already created tcp connection. cheers